# Load RSA PKCS#1 private key from memory?

Tags: crypto++

I have to write a program to establish a secure communication with a USB device. I have to use the private key generated from it which is stored in PKCS#1 format. As I have used Crypto++ in order part of my program, I would like to utilize it for this purpose as well.

However, I cannot find a way to import RSA private key from memory. It accepts private key in PKCS#8 format only. Could some pro show me a sample code on how to do it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PKCS#1 format is ASN.1 encoded. For `RSAPublicKey` and `RSAPrivateKey`, its as easy as:

```
RSA::PublicKey publicKey(...);

ByteQueue queue;
publicKey.Save(queue);

// The public key is now in the ByteQueue in PKCS #1 format

// ------------

// Load a PKCS #1 private key
byte key[] = {...}
ArraySource arr(key, sizeof(key));

RSA::PrivateKey privateKey;
privateKey.Load(arr);

// The private key is now ready to use
```

Saving and loading keys is discussed in more detail at the Crypto++ wiki under [Keys and Formats](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats).