# Load public key from unsigned char array

Tags: public-key, crypto++

I have a public key as an array of bytes from xxd:

```cxx
unsigned char publicKey_txt[] = {
 0x30, 0x82, 0x02, 0x22, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, .. };
```

From previous Stack Overflow questions I have a general understanding that in my case a `StringSink` followed by load should work

```cxx
StringSource publicstring(publicKey_txt, true, NULL);
publicKey.Load(publicstring);
```

Simply loading from text file works, but when I load from `StringSink` I get an error:

```
Error: BER decode error
```

How do I load a public key from unsigned char array?

Comment: I am open to other suggestions on how to embed the public key into my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer [from @jww - Load RSA PKCS#1 private key from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869261/load-rsa-pkcs1-private-key-from-memory?rq=1)

In my case slight modification instead of SinkSource I use the ArraySource and publicKey_txt_len is size of char array publicKey_txt.

```
CryptoPP::ArraySource as( publicKey_txt, publicKey_txt_len, true);
publicKey.Load(as);
```